Runsettings file seems to be ignored when running unit tests on pipeline
I had this problem for quite some time now and i can't seem to make it work.
I have created myself a runsettings file that i want to use in my pipeline to ignore some .cs and .cshtml files from the coverage results. From what i see the runsettings file is completely ignored (i am kinda sure the pipeline finds the file since if i change it's name it will fail the task with "File not found".
This is the pipeline:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'DotNetCore Test'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '$(uniTestProject)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code coverage" --settings coverage.runsettings'
    publishTestResults: true

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  displayName: "Publish Code Coverage Report"
  inputs:
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'

And this is my runsettings file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <Exclude>
              <ModulePath>.*Storage.*</ModulePath>
              <Source>.*\.cshtml</Source>
              <Function>CloudViewer.Program</Function>
              <Function>CloudViewer.Startup</Function>
            </Exclude>
            <OutputFormat>Cobertura</OutputFormat>
            <OutputName>MyCustomCoverage.cobertura.xml</OutputName>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>

I have already tried to specify a full path to the settings file, change it's name and run it locally with the same issues.

To exclude the .cs file, you can use <ExcludeByFile>**/<path>/*.cs</ExcludeByFile> in .runsettings.
My sample for your reference:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <Format>cobertura</Format>
          <ExcludeByFile>**/ClassLibrary1/Class2.cs</ExcludeByFile>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>

My pipeline:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet test
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**\XUnitTestProject1.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --settings XUnitTestProject1\.runsettings'

The pipeline result:

